# Converting dataframe to binary values?

Tags: r

I have a df that looks like this:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person_id = c(123L, 32432L, 34534L, 546L, 567L
), City = c("New York", "LA", "Boston", "New York", "New York"
), Disease_Heart_Failure = c(4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 8L), Disease_Covid = c(7L, 
2L, 1L, 9L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Essentially, for columns that start with `Disease_`, I want to convert the values in all of those columns. If the value in the column is 1 or greater than 1, convert the value to 1.
If the value is 0, leave it as 0.

The expected output should be:

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(Person_id = c(123L, 32432L, 34534L, 546L, 567L
), City = c("New York", "LA", "Boston", "New York", "New York"
), Disease_Heart_Failure = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Disease_Covid = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L
))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and `starts_with` to select the variables with `across`, then convert the boolean output to binary numbers by multiplying `*`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("Disease"), ~ .x >= 1) * 1)
  Person_id     City Disease_Heart_Failure Disease_Covid
1       123 New York                     1             1
2     32432       LA                     0             1
3     34534   Boston                     1             1
4       546 New York                     0             1
5       567 New York                     1             0
```

Same approach using **base R**

```
cbind(df[,!grepl("^Disease", colnames(df))], 
     (df[,grep("^Disease", colnames(df))] >= 1) * 1)
  Person_id     City Disease_Heart_Failure Disease_Covid
1       123 New York                     1             1
2     32432       LA                     0             1
3     34534   Boston                     1             1
4       546 New York                     0             1
5       567 New York                     1             0
```

Answer (score 1):

In base R, `startsWith` to identify the columns starting with "Disease",  `pmin` to restrict anything > 1 back to 1, and overwrite the changed columns.

```
sel <- startsWith(names(df), "Disease")
df[sel] <- lapply(df[sel], pmin, 1)
df

#  Person_id     City Disease_Heart_Failure Disease_Covid
#1       123 New York                     1             1
#2     32432       LA                     0             1
#3     34534   Boston                     1             1
#4       546 New York                     0             1
#5       567 New York                     1             0
```